# AlarmManager doesnt work

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

want to run the function foo() when the alarm manager runs off, but I have not understood how do I do it. I saw you pass an Intent to the alarm manager, are there other ways to do that?

Here is my code :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{   
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
   wl.acquire();

   Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
   Log.e(TAG, "ALARM!");
   wl.release();
   }

 public void SetAlarm()
 {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskOpt.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

This code doesnt work to me, as It does not get onto onRecive... what have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `onReceive()` needs to be in a class, named `TaskOpt`, that is a `BroadcastReceiver` and is registered as such in the manifest.

Second, if it is after 19:27 local time, your `Calendar` object is in the past. You need to check for this and add a day if necessary. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to find out what alarms are scheduled.

Third, I would recommend using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, or my `WakefulIntentService`, rather than using a `WakeLock` directly. Getting `WakeLock`s right is tricky, and you are better served using established patterns, implemented in existing libraries.

Beyond that, examine LogCat and see if there are any messages, and ensure that your `SetAlarm()` method is actually getting called.

Comment: Thanks! A few questions:
* How can I register the Broadcast Reciever?
* How can I use WakefulBroadcastReciver correctly? could you show me a little example ?

Comment: @Amit: "How can I register the Broadcast Reciever?" -- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html "How can I use WakefulBroadcastReciver correctly? could you show me a little example ?" -- https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast